# How to change kernel.msgmni parameter?

Tags: kernel

I would like to test Enduro/x on my ubuntu box, using the getting started guide provided with the product

It seems that i need to increase values for kernel.msgmni, kernel.msgmax and kernel.msgmnb.

Actually Enduro/x doesn't start and complain with log messages witch let me think that this kind of tuning is necessary according to the Enduro/x admin manual.

I have customized /ect/sysctl.conf for that, but when i try to apply the changes Ubuntu Linux  complains that kernel.msgmni is an invalid parameter ... i try to set it to 40000 when it's 32000 now (check with ipcs), the two other values were changed fine. Can somebody tell me why ?

My Linux install :
Ubuntu Focal Fosa : Linux MyOwnPC 5.4.0-89-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 14:50:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msgmni` has a max value of 32768 unless you add `pcmni_extend` as a command-line option for the kernel.

Set it by adding the `ipcmni_extend` option to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in `/etc/default/grub` and update grub with `sudo update-grub` before rebooting

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot for those precisions, i will give that a try and tell you back  if it solve the problem.

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind ! Your answer and some time for RTFM allowed me to change the value of msgmni :-) Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem but clearly answers the question of this post. Best regards